# Concurrent set with weak references and identity hash

Tags: java, concurrency, set, guava, weak-references

I wanted a concurrent set with weak references to elements. I thought of doing this using Guava's `MapMaker`:

```
Set<Object> concurrentSet = Collections.newSetFromMap(
    new MapMaker<Object, Boolean>().weakKeys().makeMap());
```

Guava will automatically give you identity hashes with weak keys.
However, it turns out that `MapMaker` does not allow type parameters.

```
file.java:123 type com.google.common.collect.MapMaker does not take parameters
                new MapMaker<Object, Boolean>().weakKeys().makeMap());
                            ^
```

Any solutions how I can obtain a concurrent set with weak references to elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained [in the documentation](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html), `MapMaker` is not a generic type; it's `<Object, Object>`. This means you can put anything as key or value, you just need to cast it when retreiving. Quoting the link:

```
   ConcurrentMap<Request, Stopwatch> timers = new MapMaker()
       .concurrencyLevel(4)
       .weakKeys()
       .makeMap();
```

To get a `Set` with the `Map` entries, you just call [`Map#entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29).

Comment: I wanted a concurrent set. How do I get a set from it then?

Comment: makeMap() is generic, so `ConcurrentMap<K, V> timers = new MapMaker() .concurrencyLevel(4) .weakKeys() .makeMap();` will work.

Comment: @Xaerxess didn't notice the "quote" removed "XML tags" :) Formatted it as code, thank you.

Comment: You still want `Collections.newSetFromMap` as illustrated in the original question.

Answer (score 7):

To flesh out the code being hinted at in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15978735/642706) and comments, here is my own take on the code to get a concurrent weak set.

## Java, without Guava

Using the idiom suggested in the class documentation, use [Collections.newSetFromMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap-java.util.Map-) to wrap a concurrent Map as a Set. The use of `Boolean` as the map's Value type is just filler, inconsequential.

```
Set< YourObjectTypeGoesHere > concurrentWeakSet = 
    Collections.synchronizedSet(
        Collections.newSetFromMap(
            new WeakHashMap< YourObjectTypeGoesHere , Boolean >()
        )
    )
;
```

The parameterized types can be inferred, simplifying the code to:

```
Set< YourObjectTypeGoesHere > concurrentWeakSet = 
    Collections.synchronizedSet(
        Collections.newSetFromMap(
            new WeakHashMap<>()     // Types inferred, so omitted.
        )
    )
;
```

### Guava

Alternatively, we can use `MapMaker` from the Google Guava library.

Instead of using that doc’s example wrapping a [WeakHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html), we substitute the WeakHashMap with a map from [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)’s [MapMaker](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) per the Guava doc’s suggestion to call `new MapMaker().weakKeys().makeMap()`. The Guava doc notes that this map "compares keys using object identity whereas WeakHashMap uses `Object.equals`".

## Usage

Using it is easier than understanding it!

### To Instantiate

To create the concurrent weak set, copy paste the following code. Replace two occurrences of `YourObjectTypeGoesHere`.

```
int level = 16; // Basically, the approximate number of threads that may simultaneously try to mutate the map. See Guava doc.
ConcurrentMap<YourObjectTypeGoesHere , Boolean> concurrentWeakMap = new MapMaker().concurrencyLevel( level ).weakKeys().makeMap(); // Google Guava team recommends MapMaker > weakKeys > makeMap as a replacement for weakHashMap.
Set<YourObjectTypeGoesHere> concurrentWeakSet = Collections.newSetFromMap( concurrentWeakMap ); // Concurrency protection carries over to Set wrapper.
```

### To Add

To add to the set:

```
concurrentWeakSet.add( myObject );
```

### To Iterate

To access the elements in set:

```
Iterator<YourObjectTypeGoesHere> iterator = concurrentWeakSet.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    YourObjectTypeGoesHere myObject = iterator.next();
    if( myObject != null ) { // Not sure if needed. Is it possible for object to be garbage-collected but not yet have its entry removed from the Set/Map?
       // Work with the object.
    }
}
```

## To Remove

Being weak means there is no need to remove elements. As the elements become disused and garbage-collected, they disappear from our collection (Map/Set).

Answer (score 1):

Your orriginal approach will work fine, you just have to put your type parameters on the call to `makeMap()`

```
Set<Object> concurrentSet = Collections.newSetFromMap(
new MapMaker().weakKeys().<Object, Boolean> makeMap());
```

using Java's lesser used generic method invocation syntax.
[Java Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12).